# Possible bug in QPushbutton?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to implement something similar to *Ribbon UI* found in *MS Office 2007*.
I am using `QPushbutton`'s along with `QStacked Widget`. When a `QPushbutton` is pressed corresponding `widget` from `Stacked Widget` is displayed. I want to implement in such way that when a `PushButton` is pressed down we should not be able to press it again except if some other `QPushButton` is pressed.
So for the `clicked()` `SLOT` of my `QPushButton` I am calling this: `button->setDown(true);` in my 1st line.
According to the documentation:

> If this property is true, the button is pressed down. The signals
>   pressed() and clicked() are not emitted if you set this property to
>   true.

So when I click it at run time the button is shown as pressed down. Thats good! However the `SIGNAL`'s are still emitted i.e. `pressed()` & `clicked()` are emitted.
I have tried for the same property using different combinations of `SIGNAL`'s & `SLOT`'s. However its just the same. I am using Qt 4.8.1.
What is going wrong here?
Thank You.

Comment: Sounds like you actually want to disable the control?

Comment: if it must stay down it should be checkable too (or you'll just have a button with the visual appearance of a pressed one...)

Comment: @Adriano I want the visual appearance of being pressed down yes. I also want that it should not emit the above said SIGNAL's as per the documentation. Regarding checkable, I think QPushButton does not have this property? Correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: call setCheckable(true) on the buttons, add them to an exclusive QButtonGroup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set the button visual appearance to *pressed* you can use the `setDown()` function. The documentation isn't very clear but:

> If this property is true, the button is pressed down. The signals pressed() and clicked() are not emitted if you set this property to true.

It doesn't mean that that signals won't be emitted **while** the button is pressed but that they won't be emitted **when you call `setDown()`** (after all the button is enabled and a 2nd click may simply toggle its state).

What you can do is to check if the button is pressed (`isDown()`) inside your handler for `clicked()`. As alternative you may change the button to be checkable (with `setCheckable()`)): 2nd click on the button will "close" it (if it's the behavior you need).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by
"It doesn't mean that that signals won't be emitted while the button is pressed but that they won't be emitted when you call setDown() (after all the button is enabled and a 2nd click may simply toggle its state)."
When a button is pressed the 1st time obviously the SIGNAL must be emitted. But every pressing after that should not result in SIGNAL's because I am calling setDown() in the SLOT when the button is pressed 1st time.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, I'll try to explain better: imagine documentation doesn't say that. OK? Well, now call setDown(true). We may expect that _at least_ the signal pressed() will be emitted because the button changed its state. Now put back that sentence in the documentation. You call setDown(true) but pressed() isn't emitted (**for that call**).

Comment: It means that even if setDown() will change the state of the button the **corresponding signals won't be emitted as consequence of the call to setDown()**. It doesn't mean that it'll disable that signals.

Answer (score 0):

set all the buttons to checkable and then read up on

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!
This is exactly what I wanted for my requirement of making Ribon UI.

Comment: I have already done that!
Maybe somebody down voted your answer :)
What can I do for that?
Maybe you could ask the moderators who down voted your answer...